# 1960s/70s PBS(?) Science Fiction Story - Youth Culture Quarantines Old People

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw this TV drama in the late '60s/early 70s in Los Angeles on (I think) public television. It was a sort of prequel to *Logan's Run* in which youth culture dominates the world and older folks have been sequestered.

The story: a small group of oldsters have been quarantined in an isolated hotel or rooming house with no contact with the rest of the world. All they have is a single TV channel which broadcasts youth propaganda and they are worried that the government is going to take the final step and euthanize them all. It was definitely an American production as it was filled with character actors I recognize but can't name.

Comment: sounds interesting. this theme is so compelling: besides logan's run, there was (for me) the most memorable STOS "Miri" with Kim Darby, the late Michael Pollard and the kid who was in To Kill a Mockingbird and on the cutting room floor of Godfather I. I actually will ask a question now about the first fiction with this theme.

Comment: I should have mentioned the 1968 movie 'Wild in the Streets'. The ultimate youth movie with a great final line.

Comment: Back in the day, Federal funding meant that PBS stations could be a lot more independent from the network.

Comment: I didn't know that. I saw this in Los Angeles. Does that mean it wasn't necessarily broadcast nationally?

Comment: @releseabe - this is a much more clear representation / gives understanding or context to the question you were trying to ask earlier. Things turned a little sour (not sure why, but alas) - feel free to re-ask it with a little bit clearer wording, a sharper title, etc...

Comment: Try looking at photos of older TV actors from the 60s/70s and see if you recognize anyone as someone you have seen in the show to try to ID and name them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program is "[They Have Taken Over](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1209038/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)" an episode of the *National Educational Network Playhouse* from 1970. The time is 1990 and elders are eliminated at age 65.

> In 1990, the United States government is controlled by a youthful administration who decrees that middle-aged people are a drain on resources and orders them into detention camps, where they will be killed when they reach the age of 65. Five confined artists nearing the end of their lives discuss their fate.

The actors involved were:

- Linda De Coff
- Jack Gilford
- Carmen Mathews
- Robert McLane
- Gary Merrill
- Cornelia Otis Skinner
- Joseph Wiseman